# Laravel 8 model alowed values for column

Tags: eloquent, enums, laravel-8

I need to chcek alowed values for table column like ENUM. Is it possible to set it up on model entity level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Enum and use it within your Model, and here's how you can do it:

Enum:

```
enum ServerStatus: string
{
    case Active = 'active';
    case Pending = 'pending';
}
```

Model:

```
use App\Enums\ServerStatus;
 
protected $casts = [
    'status' => ServerStatus::class,
];
```

Validation:

```
use App\Enums\ServerStatus;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;
 
$request->validate([
    'status' => [new Enum(ServerStatus::class)],
]);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#enum-casting

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-enum